# How do I add class on clicked button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I add a class on a clicked button? Do I need to make it into a class or can I add a state on a constant? I have tried to make a `handleclick` function but I don't seem to be able to fire `initialstate` on a constant.

```
const CaseListItem = ({ currentCase, onCaseSelect }) => {
console.log(currentCase);
  return (
   <div>
     <button onClick={() => onCaseSelect(currentCase)} className={currentCase.color} />
     <div className="media-heading"> {currentCase.title} </div>
   </div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in such case you should use component with state and update state color name property on click - this will re-render your component and you will be able to use state propery as class name. You can also keep this component stateless but in such case parent component should have state that will be updated when child component (`CaseListItem`) is clicked and then you can pass state color property as prop to `CaseListItem` component

Comment: What he said. Just have a value in state, either a value that represents the class name (which is initially null) or a boolean that indicates whether the button is clicked, or whatever. Then in the render function, in the className value you can have a ternary operator that applies that class based on the state value (e.g. if you're storing it as a specific value, `if state value is null, then return "", else return {this.state.className}` in the element's className value

Comment: I've tried making it to a class but gets tones of errors
class CaseListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.setState.onCaseSelect(this.state.currentCase)}
          className={this.state.currentCase.color}
        />
        <div className="media-heading">
          {this.state.currentCase.title}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: is it better to make an action of it?

Comment: Action would be ok if this application uses Redux but there is no word about Redux in question

Comment: ok sorry im using redux, really new to this. Is action a better way to do it?

Comment: If you decide to use action you will have to store this property in redux store but if you decide to not use action it will be stored in component state. So the actuall question is if you need to store this property in Redux store or maybe component state is enough? there is no simple answer - please read this discussion about this topic https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Comment: If `currentCase` property is going to be used also by other components or should be 'remembered' during whole application session then it definetly should be stored in Redux store. You can consider storing it in component state e.g. if it would be used only for temporary styling of this component